# TCP Inbound channel adaptor vers Tcp inbound channel gateway - Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

What is the difference between tcp inbound channel adaptor and tcp inbound channel gateway (Spring Integration)?

Comment: Consider adding general tags to the question for better view. You are allowed 5 tags, after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tcp adapter is for one-way integration (receives a message, and does not send a reply) whereas the gateway is for cases where you want the server to return a reply.

See the first paragraph here...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html

This is common to all Spring Integration components (adapters are one-way, gateways are for request/reply).